# How to push from one branch to another and checkout?

Tags: git

I am trying to implement the setup outlined here http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto but with one difference. On my local repository I want to use a branch different to master.

So when I go to push the initial files rather than push the master files I want to push the files from my demo branch to the master branch on the remote repository. For example:

```
git push web +master:refs/heads/demo
```

But when I do this I get the following error after it completes uploading all of the files:

```
remote: fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born
```

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do with this setup?

Comment: The refspec for push is `<src>:<dest>`. If I read your question correctly, you've inverted those.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

If the local branch is called "demo" and you want to push to branch called "master" on the remote called "web", then do the following:

```
git push web demo:master
```

If you want to merge from the "master" branch on the remote "web" into your current branch, you can do the following:

```
git fetch web
git merge web/master
```

Comment: To merge from the "master" branch on the remote "web" into your current branch, you can also simply do a "git pull web master". This essentially does the same thing as fetching it and merging it in the two separate commands specified.