# Git: can't switch to new remote branch

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch

I have an account on `github` and I use it from two different machines. On one, I created a **new branch** `myNewBranch` and switched to it. Then I did my modifications to my code, I committed and **pushed** to `myNewBranch`.

On the second machine, I can't figure out how to push to it.

```
$ git pull origin myNewBranch
From https://github.com/myUsername/myProject
 * branch            myNewBranch -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

*[ I had already successfully pulled from it]*

Then I try to switch to it, but I get an error:

```
$ git checkout myNewBranch
error: pathspec 'myNewBranch' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to fetch the data onto your local repository on machine 2 first:

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git checkout origin/myNewBranch
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! But I did a big mess: in the actions described in my question, I pulled from from myNewBranch to a different branch. Now I would actually like to keep this different branch unaltered remotely and push to myNewBranch the changes I made. Is this possible?

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550586/how-to-push-from-one-branch-to-another-and-checkout

Answer (score 12):

My guess on what happened there is a remote origin/myNewBranch, but not a local branch myNewBranch.  What your command did was to fetch origin/myNewBranch to your current local branch.  When you did the `git checkout myNewBranch`, the error happened because there was no local branch named myNewBranch.  I suggest try `git checkout -b myNewBranch origin/myNewBranch`.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing  `git checkout origin/myNewBranch`.